# Passing keyboard input to a debugged Python code in Aptana

Tags: python, debugging, keyboard, aptana

I'm working on some Python code intended to run on a Windows 7 console (AKA 'Command Prompt'). The program is capable of accepting user keyboard input, by running a dedicated thread which calls `msvcrt.getch()` which is an [MC VC++ runtime routine](http://docs.python.org/library/msvcrt.html).

I'm running into problems debugging this code on Aptana, because when I'm running the debugger, the keyboard input is redirected to the IDE, and does not "reach" the program.

The scenario is as follows:

- Run the code under the debugger (App Explorer --> right-click main.py --> Debug As --> Python Run)
- The 'Aptana Scripting Console' starts showing the program's stdout.
- In the scripting console, I hit user input, but instead of being passed to the running program, it is intercepted by the IDE to allow me to interactively evaluate Python statements with the program's context available (a great feature in most cases)

My question is: Is it possible to bypass or temporarily disable this behavior, so that the keystrokes are passed to the debbuged application?